# Count the number of columns with ID x in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the columns that have the same name. I need a formula to apply it to all data.

[image: Example]

For example, I am trying to count the amount of cloumns with ID=11 and write them in row "N".

Is there a simple formula for this?

Comment: This is a entry level excel via `COUNTIF`. I suspect you didn't bother doing any research on this before posting. Try `COUNTIF(A:A, A1)` and drag down.

Comment: I did, I did not find anthing which fits.

Comment: Confused how you searched and didn't find anything. I searched the exact title of your question and the first 3 suggestions via Google were about `COUNTIF`. Glad that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

```
=COUNTIF(A3:A25, 11)
```